# SqlDataSource OnInserted Fired Prematurely

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a SqlDataSource that has an OnInserted handler.  The handler sends an email with data gleaned from the Inserted record.  Including it's ID (an output parameter).

Yesterday, I have an email sent by the handler that has a timestamp of 4:00pm.  20 minutes prior to the timestamp of the record being committed in SQL.  If you're thinking it's machine time differences between the web/sql/exchange servers...I've already ruled that out.  The Insert is performed by a stored procedure.  It insterts records in several tables.  All of which have a 4:20pm timestamp.

Also, the email contained an inaccurate ID.  Consistent with the record not being committed at the time the email was sent.

The question is, how is it possible that the email sent by the SqlDataSource's OnInserted handler, was sent before the record was committed in SQL?

```
protected void On_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //GET THE RECORD ID
        String RecordID = String.Empty;
        RecordID = e.Command.Parameters["@RecordID"].Value != null ? e.Command.Parameters["@RecordID"].Value.ToString() : String.Empty;

        //SEND THE EMAIL
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SmtpHere",##);
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
        email.From = new MailAddress("FromAddressHere");
        email.To.Add("ToAddressHere")
        email.Subject = "Example Email";
        email.Body = "The record #" + RecordID + " was just added.";
        smtp.Send(email);
        smtp = null;
        email.Dispose();

        //GO TO THE PAGE WITH THE NEW RECORD ID
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Page.aspx?RecordID=" + RecordID, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //HANDLE EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide your event code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your e-mail code (in the `SqlDataSource.Inserted` event) doesn't check the [`SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs.AffectedRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.aspx) property to make sure a row was actually inserted:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_OnInserted(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.AffectedRows > 0)
    {
        // Send e-mail
    }
    else
    {
        // For some reason, the insert didn't happen.  Check for exceptions
        string errorMessage = e.Exception.InnerException.Message;
        // Here you want to display this error to the user, or log it, or something
    }
}
```

So what I think happened was:

1. E-mail fires off, even though the record wasn't really inserted yet
2. 20 minutes later, another insert operation happens that is actually successful.  Another e-mail is generated, rows are inserted, etc.

It's unsurprising that this type of mistake might go unnoticed for a while, as your inserts probably fail pretty infrequently.

Comment: So, if OnInserted doesn't wait for the Insert statement to be committed, what then is the trigger to fire OnInserted?  My understanding was that OnInserted fires after the Insert statement completed.  From msdn:  "Raises the Inserted event after the SqlDataSource control has completed an insert operation."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourceview.oninserted(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @s15199d Right, that is the confusing part. The Insert operation *has* completed, from the perspective of the `SqlDataSource` (in the sense that it constructed an SQLstatement, sent that to the database, and got some kind of response). It doesn't say "*after a successful insert operation was executed on the database*". That's why they send you the `Exception` and `ExceptionHandled` properties - it's up to the developer to decide what to do about that.

Comment: Thanks @jadarnel!  Your response is spot on.

Comment: @s15199d Glad I could help.  I have had this problem before =)